# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros a una Ruta nombrada en Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

Tengo un Inconveniente al querer pasar parámetros a una ruta nombra en Laravel.
Al pasar los Paremetros de esta forma con Javascript

```
    let url ="{{ route('ordenes.ordenPreventiva',['id' => 'temp']) }}"
    url = url.replace('temp',id);
    location.href=url;
```

el parametro es visible en la url
[image: Imagen de la Url]
Pero al Intentar Obtener en el Controlador

```
Route::get('/ordenPreventiva/{id}',[HomeController::class,"crearOrdenPreventiva"])->name('ordenes.ordenPreventiva');
```

me sale el siguiente error:

[image: imagen error]

Segun la documentacion de Laravel, creo que es la manera correcta de pasar paremetros entre rutas nombradas, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.
Segun yo no tendria que poder ver de esta manera la url

[image: Imagen de la Url]
Si me pueden dar una Mano estaría Muy agradecido.
Pd(Si le es util estoy utilizando AdminLte como plantilla par el Proyecto)

Comment: debes mandar el id sin nombre,ya la ruta entiende que ese es el id despues del /  ..ordenes/orderPreventiva/51

Answer (score 0):

No ceseitas definir la variable en el show ya que la ruta sabe que despues del / el parametro es el id.
solo mira la ruta y donde esta **{}** quiere decir que eso lo reemplazas por tu variable

```
/ordenPreventiva/{id}
```

**Quedaria asi:**

```
192.168.0.29/ordenes/ordenPreventiva/51
```